# Equivalent definitions of connected components

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

A long time ago, I learned the definition of **(connected) components** from Munkres's topology textbook, which defines a connected component of a topological space $X$ as an **equivalence class** under an equivalence relation $\sim$ by setting $x\sim y$ if there is a connected subspace of $X$ that contains both $x$ and $y$.

Later, I found another definition of connected components from Lee's manifold textbook, which defines a connected component of $X$ as a **maximal connected subset**, meaning a connected subset that cannot be properly contained in any other connected subset.

I would like to prove these two definitions are in fact equivalent; however, I would have to assume $X$ is not the empty space. Please, can you check if there is any error in my proof? Thank you.

==================Below is my proof==========================

1. Suppose $S$ is a maximal connected subset of $X$. We have to show $S$ is an equivalence class under $\sim$, that is, find $y^*\in X$ so that $S$ is the equivalence class of $y^*$ under $\sim$, denoted by $y^*/\sim$. First we observe that $S$ cannot be empty, for if $S=\emptyset$, and $z\in X$, then $S$ would be a proper subset of the connected set $z/\sim$, violating the fact that $S$ is a maximal connected set. Since $S$ is non-empty, we can choose $y\in S$. We claim that $S=y/\sim$. That $S\subseteq y/\sim$ is obvious because $S$ is a connected subspace of $X$.
2. Suppose $S$ is a connected component of $X$. We have to show $S$ is a maximal connected subset of $X$. Suppose not. Then there must be a connected subset $T$ of $X$ such that $S$ is a proper subset of $T$. Now, since $S$ is a connected component of $X$, $\exists y\in X$ s.t. $S=y/\sim$. On the other hand, because the difference $T\setminus S$ is non-empty, we can choose $z\in T\setminus S$. Seeing $z\notin S$, we obtain $z\not\sim y$, contradicting the fact that $z,y\in T$.

**Note.** In this proof, we have assume familiarity with properties of equivalence classes, and the fact that any equivalence class under $\sim$ is a connected subset of $X$.

**Edit 1.** The claim in the first half of the proof remains unresolved. I'm working on the proof that $y/\sim\subseteq S$.

**Edit 2.** To justify the claim, I think we can make use of the assumption that $S$ is a maximal connected subset. That way, because the connected subset $y/\sim$ has been proved to contain $S$, we are forced to conclude $S=y/\sim$.

Comment: I think 2. is correct. For 1., you can directly show that $y/ \sim$ $\textbf{is}$ the maximal connected subset of $X$ containing $y$ (this is exactly what you have done in fact). In particular, the reverse inclusion is trivial. Specifically, you can show that $y/ \sim$ is the union over all the connected subsets of $X$ containing $y$.

Comment: @NaNoS Hello, can you take a look at my new edit, please? Thank you.

Comment: Your second edit is correct, maybe the point (which you seem to be aware of) is that the equivalence class is indeed a connected subspace of $X$. Then, if $S$ is maximal and if $S \subset y/ \sim$, of course you have equality as you said.

Comment: @NaNoS Yes, my friend, I have known that every equivalence class under $\sim$ is a connected subspace.

Answer (score 1):

One can be concise saying that, for every $x$ in $X$ (of course if $X$ is not empty), the equivalence class $x/ \sim$ is (*) the union of all the connected subspaces of $X$ containing $x$. Now, if $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ is a collection of connected subspaces of $X$ (note that $I$ can be wathever you want) such that $\cap_{i \in I} C_i \neq \emptyset$, then $\cup_{i \in I} C_i$ is connected. Apply this to $x/ \sim$ to deduce that it is a connected space containing $x$ and, by (*), is the maximal subspace of $X$ satisfying this condition. In particular, the two definitions are equivalent.